# Spring-XD: Jobs automatic undeployment on zookeeper time-out in xd-singlenode mode

Tags: spring-batch, spring-xd

I am running spring-xd in singlenode mode. My job has job module which may run for more than 10 minutes. When I launch the job, Seeing following timeouts followed by undeployment of my jobs and modules.
Do I need to change any zookeeper settings? Please advise -

First error

```
2015-01-26 20:30:22,514 [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] [] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 40465ms for sessionid 0x14b28fc8fa80000, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
2015-01-26 20:30:22,516 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181] [] WARN org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn  - caught end of stream exception
EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x14b28fc8fa80000, likely client has closed socket
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2015-01-26 20:30:22,518 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181] [] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn  - Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:48599 which had sessionid 0x14b28fc8fa80000
2015-01-26 20:30:22,615 [main-EventThread] [] INFO org.apache.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager  - State change: SUSPENDED
2015-01-26 20:30:22,616 [DeploymentSupervisorCacheListener-0] [] INFO org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.InitialDeploymentListener  - Path cache event: type=CONNECTION_SUSPENDED
2015-01-26 20:30:22,616 [ConnectionStateManager-0] [] INFO org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.DeploymentSupervisor  - Admin admin:default,admin,singlenode:9393 connection suspended
2015-01-26 20:30:22,628 [ConnectionStateManager-0] [] INFO org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.ContainerRegistrar  - ZooKeeper connection suspended: 9adc3b5e-1b19-4d64-9b52-a5643dc42acb
2015-01-26 20:30:22,649 [LeaderSelector-0] [] INFO org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.DeploymentSupervisor  - Leadership canceled due to thread interrupt
2015-01-26 20:30:22,650 [DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0] [] INFO org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.DeploymentListener  - Path cache event: type=CONNECTION_SUSPENDED
2015-01-26 20:30:22,678 [DeploymentSupervisorCacheListener-0] [] INFO org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.InitialDeploymentListener  - Path cache event: type=CONNECTION_SUSPENDED
2015-01-26 20:30:23,712 [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] [] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2015-01-26 20:30:23,713 [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] [] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
2015-01-26 20:30:23,713 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181] [] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory  - Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:49181
2015-01-26 20:30:23,715 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181] [] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer  - Client attempting to renew session 0x14b28fc8fa80000 at /127.0.0.1:49181
2015-01-26 20:30:23,715 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181] [] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer  - Established session 0x14b28fc8fa80000 with negotiated timeout 60000 for client /127.0.0.1:49181
2015-01-26 20:30:23,716 [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] [] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x14b28fc8fa80000, negotiated timeout = 60000
2015-01-26 20:30:59,587 [main-EventThread] [] ERROR org.apache.curator.ConnectionState  - Connection timed out for connection string (localhost:2181) and timeout (15000) / elapsed (36877)
org.apache.curator.CuratorConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
        at org.apache.curator.ConnectionState.checkTimeouts(ConnectionState.java:198)
        at org.apache.curator.ConnectionState.getZooKeeper(ConnectionState.java:88)
        at org.apache.curator.CuratorZookeeperClient.getZooKeeper(CuratorZookeeperClient.java:115)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.getZooKeeper(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:474)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetDataBuilderImpl$4.call(GetDataBuilderImpl.java:302)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetDataBuilderImpl$4.call(GetDataBuilderImpl.java:291)
        at org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:107)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetDataBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(GetDataBuilderImpl.java:287)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetDataBuilderImpl.forPath(GetDataBuilderImpl.java:279)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetDataBuilderImpl.forPath(GetDataBuilderImpl.java:41)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.DeploymentListener$JobModuleWatcher.process(DeploymentListener.java:527)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.NamespaceWatcher.process(NamespaceWatcher.java:67)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.processEvent(ClientCnxn.java:522)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:498)
```

Followed by un-deployments of jobs

```
2015-01-26 20:31:35,462 [LeaderSelector-1] [] INFO org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.DeploymentSupervisor  - Leader Admin admin:default,admin,singlenode:9393 is watching for stream/job deployment requests.
2015-01-26 20:31:35,463 [ConnectionStateManager-0] [] INFO org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.ContainerRegistrar  - Waiting for supervisor to clean up prior deployments (elapsed time 0 seconds)...
2015-01-26 20:31:35,463 [ConnectionStateManager-0] [] INFO org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.ContainerRegistrar  - Waiting for supervisor to clean up prior deployments (elapsed time 0 seconds)...
2015-01-26 20:31:35,478 [DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0] [] INFO org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.DeploymentListener  - Path cache event: path=/deployments/modules/allocated/9adc3b5e-1b19-4d64-9b52-a5643dc42acb/c1_Job.job.custom-mod-hdfs.1, type=CHILD_REMOVED
2015-01-26 20:31:35,478 [DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0] [] INFO org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.DeploymentListener  - Undeploying module [ModuleDescriptor@593edefc moduleName = 'custom-mod-hdfs', moduleLabel = 'custom-mod-hdfs', group = 'c1_Job', sourceChannelName = [null], sinkChannelName = [null], sinkChannelName = [null], index = 0, type = job, parameters = map['table' -> 'c1', 'mode' -> 'initial'], children = list[[empty]]]
2015-01-26 20:31:35,516 [main-EventThread] [] INFO org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.DeploymentListener  - Undeploying module [ModuleDescriptor@4a83d881 moduleName = 'custom-mod-hdfs', moduleLabel = 'custom-mod-hdfs', group = 'c2_Job', sourceChannelName = [null], sinkChannelName = [null], sinkChannelName = [null], index = 0, type = job, parameters = map['fetchSize' -> '100000', 'table' -> 'counts', 'mode' -> 'initial'], children = list[[empty]]]
2015-01-26 20:31:35,562 [DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0] [] INFO org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.DeploymentListener  - Path cache event: path=/deployments/modules/allocated/9adc3b5e-1b19-4d64-9b52-a5643dc42acb/c2_job.job.custom-mod-hdfs.1, type=CHILD_REMOVED
2015-01-26 20:31:35,562 [DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0] [] INFO org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.DeploymentListener  - Undeploying module [ModuleDescriptor@6d07b3ed moduleName = 'custom-mod-hdfs', moduleLabel = 'custom-mod-hdfs', group = 'c2_Job', sourceChannelName = [null], sinkChannelName = [null], sinkChannelName = [null], index = 0, type = job, parameters = map['table' -> 'c2', 'mode' -> 'initial'], children = list[[empty]]]
2015-01-26 20:31:35,577 [DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0] [] INFO org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.DeploymentListener  - Path cache event: path=/deployments/modules/allocated/9adc3b5e-1b19-4d64-9b52-a5643dc42acb/c3_job.custom-mod-hdfs.1, type=CHILD_REMOVED
2015-01-26 20:31:35,578 [main-EventThread] [] INFO org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.DeploymentListener  - Undeploying module [ModuleDescriptor@13097137 moduleName = 'custom-mod-hdfs', moduleLabel = 'custom-mod-hdfs', group = 'c3_Job', sourceChannelName = [null], sinkChannelName = [null], sinkChannelName = [null], index = 0, type = job, parameters = map['table' -> 'c3', 'mode' -> 'initial'], children = list[[empty]]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring XD single node mode runs an embedded ZooKeeper server in the same JVM as the ZooKeeper "client" - i.e. the application context that is hosting the job module. If there is a 40 second gap between heartbeats, this is probably an indication that the JVM is experiencing heavy GC and/or the host machine has run out of physical memory and is swapping to disk.

To test this theory out, I suggest enabling verbose gc. This can be done by modifying the `xd-singlenode` script or by setting the environment variable `export JAVA_OPTS=-verbose:gc` before launching the script.

To modify the session and connection timeouts, you can set the following JVM system properties:

- `curator-default-session-timeout` - session timeout
- `curator-default-connection-timeout` - connection timeout

Comment: Full GC is the reason for timeout. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: I tried increasing the session timeout as suggested above, still seeing below entry in log - 

org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=60000 

Below are my system properties in xd-singlenode script -
DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS="-verbose:gc -Dcurator-default-session-timeout=300000 -Dcurator-default-connection-timeout=300000"

Comment: Any suggestions on increasing timeout. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I gave it a quick try and saw that the session timeouts were not taking effect. I'll look into it more and update this post when I find out what's going on.

Comment: What version of Spring XD are you running? If it is 1.1.0 (including RC1) you should modify the sessionTimeout setting in servers.yml - see http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.1.0.RC1/reference/html/#setting-up-zookeeper. In prior versions setting the system property works for me.

Comment: I am running 1.0.3 version. I will double check on this.

Comment: I tested again in 1.0.3 by passing system properties "-Dcurator-default-session-timeout=300000 -Dcurator-default-connection-timeout=30000". Same issue is present. Somehow it is still taking 60000 ms as default timeout value.

Answer (score 2):

Since this issue caused us quite some headache I'd like to share here what we did in order to solve this. I guess that some of you out there might have a similar setup and I hope to save you some hours for tracking down your specific problem.

Especially if you are seeing logs such as

```
09:48:21,467 1.1.1.RELEASE  WARN SyncThread:0 persistence.FileTxnLog - fsync-ing the write ahead log in SyncThread:0 took 1123ms which will adversely effect operation latency. See the ZooKeeper troubleshooting guide
```

you might be in the same trouble as we were (just an educated guess that lead us to the idea that the system is in a really bad condition)

Actually, the GC pause was not solely caused by our app. We are running XD in single node mode (as a starter option until we need to scale) and a MySQL database on the server. We are mainly scheduling Jobs with XD that are triggered by external events bubbling into the system (and thus being somehow unpredictable).

In the end our problem was

- An expensive database query
- Database results loaded into memory by MySQL JDBC driver
- Java Garbage Collection

The GC Pause was caused because of overall System Load (the database caused an unusually high load on the system) + the fact that the JVM tries to avoid OutOfMemory situations wherever possible (interesting side fact - I have rarely seen OutOfMemory exceptions since we are using Java 8 - so there might have been changes there ...) + the fact that XD thinks (and is right) that the system doesn't behave stable, so it's better to tear it down and someone else will hopefully pick it's modules up (which will not happen in this case).

Tracking this down isn't easy. First we had to somehow bring the system into trouble by firing a lot of events on it. We used htop and saw that memory is OK and that CPU is OK - but it showed us that the system is unusually busy nevertheless. So IO was left - we used iotop in order to track down MySQL as being the bad guy. We've tracked down the queries using MySQLs "SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST" command. Next up was to limit the heap available to the XD container so that a memory dump (created with jmap) would fit into our developer machines and use a profiler (YourKit in our case) in order to track down the memory problem. In our case it was MySQL - and we solved the problem by switching to cursor fetch mode for the affected queries, see e.g. http://codewut.de/content/mysql-large-result-sets-and-outofmemory-related-headaches

Answer (score 0):

By adding the following system properties in `xd-singlenode.sh`, Zookeeper timeout settings can be easily modified. I verified this on `Spring-XD-1.1.1.Release` version.

```
-Dzk.namespace=xd -Dzk.client.sessionTimeout=300000 
-Dzk.client.connectionTimeout=150000 -DzkInitialRetryWait=1000 
-Dzk.client.retryMaxAttempts=3
```